# Generic protocol for observing changes in Swift 5

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift5

Trying hard to code in Swift 5 the Java example below.

Generally, I want to have an `Observable` protocol which will be adopted by multiple other protocols. I need these protocols to be types in functions' arguments, so that these functions can add additional observers.

In Java, it is very easy to do. The code prints out:

```
Observer 1 changed to 10
Observer 2 changed to 10
```

,

```
interface Observable<O> {
    void addObserver(O observer);
}

interface Settings extends Observable<SettingsObserver> {
    void setInterval(int interval);
}

interface SettingsObserver {
    void intervalChanged(int interval);
}

class AppSettings implements Settings {
    private List<SettingsObserver> observers = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override public void addObserver(SettingsObserver observer) { observers.add(observer); }
    @Override public void setInterval(int interval) { observers.forEach(observer -> observer.intervalChanged(interval)); }
}

class Observer1 implements SettingsObserver {
    @Override public void intervalChanged(int interval) {
        System.out.println("Observer 1 changed to " + interval);
    }
}

class Observer2 implements SettingsObserver {
    @Override public void intervalChanged(int interval) {
        System.out.println("Observer 2 changed to " + interval);
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observer1 observer1 = new Observer1();

        Settings settings = new AppSettings();
        settings.addObserver(observer1);

        Main main = new Main();
        main.run(settings);
    }

    void run(Settings settings) {
        Observer2 observer2 = new Observer2();
        settings.addObserver(observer2);

        settings.setInterval(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift already has setter observers. You don’t need a protocol for this.

Comment: Well, this is a simplified case. I need to observe an instance state and give observers feedback if certain conditions change.

Comment: For more complex observability look into Key Value Observing or the new Combine framework. Do not reinvent the wheel. A generic protocol cannot be used as a type in Swift so don’t try to go down that road.

Comment: @matt and @OP I don't see the `Observer` interface being used as a parameter or variable type, so couldn't you just translate the Java directly to Swift (though I know it might not be the most Swifty code)?

Comment: @Sweeper Well the OP didn't show _any_ Swift code; therefore so far we are just waving our hands. There is no actual question on the table.

Comment: I think property observers should work fine even for instance state instead of a single property. Instance state is made up of multiple properties. Using didSet {...} on the relevant properties and funnelling through a single checker is probably enough.

Comment: @matt KVO is not usable for me as it requires the whole protocol chain to be `objc` annotated. And the protocol also contains an Enum which cannot be represented in ObjC and hence the compilation fails.

Comment: Yes, well, as you have refused to show any Swift code or say what problem you are actually having with it, that's as far as I can go for the moment.

Comment: @matt Sorry, I am not refusing to show the code. Let me prepare it and share it in the question.

Comment: @PavelLobodinský The real problem is probably the fact that you are trying to create a protocol chain. That seems like the root architecture problem. Instead of observer being an object as is typical in Java (mainly because of historical reasons), use closures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's simple to create a generic wrapper to which you can add your own observables, there are two *native* solutions that you should use instead.

1. Notifications.

   When value is changed, send a notification using `NotificationCenter.default`. Observers should listen to these notifications. Notification are a crucial part of the ecosystem:

   ```
   class AppSettings {
       enum Notifications {
           static let intervalChanged = Notification.Name("AppSettingsIntervalChangedNotification")
       }

       var interval: TimeInterval = 0 {
           didSet {
               NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notifications.intervalChanged, object: self)
           }
       }
   }

   let settings = AppSettings()
   let observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
       forName: AppSettings.Notifications.intervalChanged,
       object: settings,
       queue: nil
   ) { [weak settings] _ in
       guard let settings = settings else { return }
       print(settings.interval)
   }

   settings.interval = 10
   ```
2. Key-value observing (KVO)

   If you inherit your objects from `NSObject`, you can simply add a direct observer to any Obj-C compatible value:

   ```
   class AppSettings: NSObject {
       @objc dynamic var interval: TimeInterval = 0
   }

   let settings = AppSettings()

   let observer: NSKeyValueObservation = settings.observe(\.interval, options: .new) { _, change in
       print(change.newValue)
   }

   settings.interval = 10
   ```

   See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift

Just for completeness a simple generic observer here:

```
class Observable<ValueType> {
    typealias Observer = (ValueType) -> Void

    var observers: [Observer] = []
    var value: ValueType {
        didSet {
            for observer in observers {
                observer(value)
            }
        }
    }

    init(_ defaultValue: ValueType) {
        value = defaultValue
    }

    func addObserver(_ observer: @escaping Observer) {
        observers.append(observer)
    }
}

class AppSettings {
    let interval: Observable<TimeInterval> = Observable(0)
}

let settings = AppSettings()
settings.interval.addObserver { interval in
    print(interval)
}
settings.interval.value = 10
```

Note that all my observers are simple closures. The reason why Java uses objects as observers is mostly historical due to Java limitations. There is no need for `Observable` or `Observer` protocols in Swift.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The way with notifications will do the job nicely.

Comment: @PavelLobodinský Also note that the direct counterpart of Java observer objects would be *delegates*. However, since Swift does not have a garbage collector, you would need an array that holds instances as weak references. And that would bring another level of complexity. By the way, we are former colleagues :)

Comment: Whohoo, a mystery former coworker I have no idea who he is :D

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you may be able to get by with [property observers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID262) in Swift.  It allows you to take action when a property is going to be changed or has changed.  It is also less complicated than a full observerable type.

Here is Apple's example from the Swift manual:

```
class StepCounter {
    var totalSteps: Int = 0 {
        willSet(newTotalSteps) {
            print("About to set totalSteps to \(newTotalSteps)")
        }
        didSet {
            if totalSteps > oldValue  {
                print("Added \(totalSteps - oldValue) steps")
            }
        }
    }
}
let stepCounter = StepCounter()
stepCounter.totalSteps = 200
// About to set totalSteps to 200
// Added 200 steps
stepCounter.totalSteps = 360
// About to set totalSteps to 360
// Added 160 steps
stepCounter.totalSteps = 896
// About to set totalSteps to 896
// Added 536 steps
```

You would want to use the didSet() function.  You could also call another function within the observer.

You could also use the property observers to write a simple observable-like class if you do not want to use a framework such as RxSwift or Apple's new Combine.

Here is a simple example that just uses closures instead of classes:

```
class ClassToWatch {
    typealias ObservingFunc = (ClassToWatch) -> Void
    private var observers: [ObservingFunc] = []
    func addObserver(_ closure: @escaping ObservingFunc) {
        observers.append(closure)
    }

    private func valueChanged() {
        observers.forEach { observer in
            observer(self)
        }
    }

    var value1: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            valueChanged()
        }
    }

    var value2: String = "" {
        didSet {
            valueChanged()
        }
    }
}

var myclass = ClassToWatch()
myclass.addObserver { object in
    print("Observer 1: \(object.value1) \(object.value2)")
}
myclass.addObserver { object in
    print("Observer 2: \(object.value1) \(object.value2)")
}

myclass.value1 = 3
myclass.value2 = "Test"
```

Comment: Yes, observing a simple property is straightforward. However, I need to observe an instance state, and notify observers when certain conditions change.

Comment: If you want something more sophisticated perhaps you want to check out the RxSwift or Combine frameworks.

Comment: I added a simple idea using closures if you want to avoid using framework.  There are many ways you could solve it but I am not sure which method is best for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your Java code could be directly translated into Swift code. Here is my translation, with some degree of "Swiftification":

```
protocol Observable {
    associatedtype ObserverType

    func addObserver(_ observer: ObserverType)
}

protocol Settings : Observable where ObserverType == SettingsObserver {
    var interval: Int { get set }
}

protocol SettingsObserver {
    func intervalDidChange(newValue: Int)
}

class Observer1 : SettingsObserver {
    func intervalDidChange(newValue: Int) {
        print("Observer 1 changed to \(newValue)")
    }
}
class Observer2 : SettingsObserver {
    func intervalDidChange(newValue: Int) {
        print("Observer 2 changed to \(newValue)")
    }
}

class AppSettings: Settings {
    var interval: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            observers.forEach { $0.intervalDidChange(newValue: interval) }
        }
    }
    private var observers: [SettingsObserver] = []

    func addObserver(_ observer: SettingsObserver) {
        observers.append(observer)
    }
}

let settings = AppSettings()
settings.addObserver(Observer1())
settings.addObserver(Observer2())
settings.interval = 10
```

Although `Observable` cannot be used as a parameter type, the protocols that derive from it that also specifies the associated type, can.

You could go one step further and make `SettingsObserver` a typealias of `(Int) -> Void`. This way you don't need all those different `ObserverX` classes.

```
typelias SettingsObserver = (Int) -> Void
```

The `addObserver` calls would then become:

```
settings.addObserver { print("Observer 1 changed to \($0)") }
settings.addObserver { print("Observer 2 changed to \($0)") }
```

And the call in `didSet` would change to:

```
observers.forEach { $0(interval) }
```

Also, I don't understand why `Settings` exist. Can't you just conform `AppSettings` directly to `Observable`? I mean, I know the idea of program to interface and all that, but IMO this is a bit too much...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that helped a lot. My example was a bit simplified, that's the reason it doesn't make sense why the Settings class exists.